MongoDB aggregate merge condition
I have this below collection and I use MongoDB aggregation to acheive an output(where I aggregate all order line items for an order) and trying to merge into another collection(order).
[
  {
    "order_line_item_id": 1,
    "order_id": 100,
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Shoe",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pant",
        "hasDefect": "NO"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shirt",
        "hasDefect": "NOT_SURE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "order_line_item_id": 2,
    "order_id": 100,
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Shoe",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pant",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shirt",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "order_line_item_id": 3,
    "order_id": 101,
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Shoe",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pant",
        "hasDefect": "NO"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shirt",
        "hasDefect": "NOT_SURE"
      }
    ]
  }
]

I use the below aggregation to achieve the output
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      order_id: {
        $eq: 100
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$products"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "products.name": {
        $eq: "Pant"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        order_id: "$order_id",
        productName: "$products.name"
      },
      hasDefects: {
        $push: "$products.hasDefect"
      },
      products: {
        $push: "$products"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      hasDefect: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $allElementsTrue: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$hasDefects",
                    as: "d",
                    in: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$d",
                        "YES"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              then: "YES"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $in: [
                  "NO",
                  "$hasDefects"
                ]
              },
              then: "NO"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $in: [
                  "NOT_SURE",
                  "$hasDefects"
                ]
              },
              then: "NOT_SURE"
            }
          ],
          default: "<DEFAULT>"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.order_id",
      order_id: {
        "$first": "$_id.order_id"
      },
      products: {
        $push: {
          name: "$_id.productName",
          hasDefect: "$hasDefect",
          lastModified: {
            $dateToString: {
              date: new Date(),
              timezone: "America/New_York"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "_id"
    ]
  },
  { 
    $merge: { 
      into: "order_res", 
      on: [ "order_id" ], 
      whenMatched: "replace", 
      whenNotMatched: "insert" 
    }
  }
])

The output can be a new document altogether or an update for one of the products in the order document (like below).
[
  {    
    "order_id": 100,
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Shoe",
        "hasDefect": "YES"
      },
    ]
  }
]   

I m using the merge aggregation stage to insert/update to another mongoDB collection.
{ $merge: { into: "order", on: "order_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" }}
The issue is it is an update operation and the order has previous products it replace all existing product with this new one.
For example if the order has the below document, it should update only "Shoe" product.
[
  {    
    "order_id": 100,
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Shoe",
        "hasDefect": "NO"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pant",
        "hasDefect": "NO"
      },
      {
        "name": "Shirt",
        "hasDefect": "NOT_SURE"
      }
    ]
  }
]


the second code block is the update array? can it have multiple items. if so is the order_id same for all. will the update happen to both the docs with order_line_item_id 1 and 2

@cmgchess I have updated the post also. Yes the update array can have multiple items and will have the same order_id

Referring to the query from my previous answer,
You can provide the aggregation pipeline to whenMatched.
An important key is to refer to the (result) field returned from the aggregation pipeline, you need to use the $$new variable.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$products"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        order_id: "$order_id",
        productName: "$products.name"
      },
      hasDefects: {
        $push: "$products.hasDefect"
      },
      products: {
        $push: "$products"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      hasDefect: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $allElementsTrue: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$hasDefects",
                    as: "d",
                    in: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$d",
                        "YES"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              then: "YES"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $in: [
                  "NO",
                  "$hasDefects"
                ]
              },
              then: "NO"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $in: [
                  "NOT_SURE",
                  "$hasDefects"
                ]
              },
              then: "NOT_SURE"
            }
          ],
          default: "<DEFAULT>"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.order_id",
      products: {
        $push: {
          name: "$_id.productName",
          hasDefect: "$hasDefect"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "order",
      whenMatched: [
        {
          $addFields: {
            products: {
              $let: {
                vars: {
                  newProducts: "$$new.products"
                },
                in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$products",
                        as: "oldProduct",
                        in: {
                          $cond: {
                            if: {
                              $in: [
                                "$$oldProduct.name",
                                "$$newProducts.name"
                              ]
                            },
                            then: {
                              $first: {
                                $filter: {
                                  input: "$$newProducts",
                                  cond: {
                                    $eq: [
                                      "$$this.name",
                                      "$$oldProduct.name"
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            else: "$$oldProduct"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$$newProducts",
                        cond: {
                          $not: {
                            $in: [
                              "$$this.name",
                              "$products.name"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      whenNotMatched: "insert"
    }
  }
])

Demo @ Mongo Playground

I tried and it does not update an existing product. it just adds to the product array.
For example {"order_id": 100,"products": [{"name": "Shoe","hasDefect": "YES"}]} gets added as another Shoe product in the collection although the collection has Shoe product and it should have just updated it.

Can you reproduce your scenario with the data in the Mongo Playground? The demo I put in the answer can't reproduce your scenario.

My Bad it actually works.  I had one of the variable names incorrect, so it could not find and was always appending.
I have one question in how this works:
$in: [   "$$oldProduct.name",   "$$newProducts.name"]
I m curious how  "$$newProducts.name" resolves to an array?

Hi, MongoDB has the ability to access the nested field and return it, as newProducts is an array, hence with $$newProducts.name, it will return all the name values as an array. The purpose of using $in is to check the $$oldProduct.name exists in the $$newProducts.name array.

You can make use of $mergeObjects in place of $merge to create the new collection with the desired documents.
Please let me know if the below query works for you:


[
  {
    $match: {
      order_id: 100
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$products"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "products.name": "Pant"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        order_id: "$order_id",
        productName: "$products.name"
      },
      hasDefects: {
        $push: "$products.hasDefect"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      hasDefect: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $allElementsTrue: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$hasDefects",
                    as: "d",
                    in: {
                      $eq: ["$$d", "YES"]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              then: "YES"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $in: ["NO", "$hasDefects"]
              },
              then: "NO"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $in: ["NOT_SURE", "$hasDefects"]
              },
              then: "NOT_SURE"
            }
          ],
          default: "<DEFAULT>"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      order_id: "$_id.order_id",
      productName: "$_id.productName",
      hasDefect: "$hasDefect",
      lastModified: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: new Date(),
          timezone: "America/New_York"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "order",
      whenMatched: [
        {
          $addFields: {
            products: {
              $map: {
                input: "$$ROOT.products",
                as: "product",
                in: {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $eq: ["$$product.name", "$productName"]
                    },
                    then: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$product",
                        { hasDefect: "$hasDefect" }
                      ]
                    },
                    else: "$$product"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      whenNotMatched: "insert"
    }
  }
]



Best Regards
Aasawari

The order collection will also have an array of products. You replaced the second $group with $project. Which is not working for me.
